# how to change file from codepage 936 to utf-8 by elixir code?

Tags: elixir

I have found [`codepage`](https://hex.pm/packages?search=codepage&sort=recent_downloads) for transform string's codepage.

If for the whole file transform, is there any solution?

Comment: If you want the whole file transformed, I’d go with the regular `iconv` library. Adding stream support to `codepagex` does not seem to be rather complicated too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input encoding was `latin-1`, it could be done by bare [erlang](/questions/tagged/erlang) with [`:unicode.characters_to_binary/2`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html#characters_to_binary-2).

For exotic encodings, one should probably use [`iconv`](https://github.com/processone/iconv#elixir) as below.

```elixir
:iconv.convert("cp936", "utf-8", text)
```

Do not forget to include `{:iconv, "~> 1.0"}` dependency and make sure `libiconv` is available.